# realloc() invalid pointer error when increasing size of string in a function

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, c89

When i run code it show `realloc()` invalid pointer error.

Is anything wrong in `input()` function?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
char *input(void)
{
    int n = 1;
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char));
    *str = '\0';
    while((*str=getchar())!='\n')
    {
        n++;
        str = realloc(str,sizeof(char)*n);
        str++;
    }
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *str = input();
    printf("%s",str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make a few errors:

- you return the end of the string, not the beginning.
- `realloc` needs the original address (see Thomas' answer)
- `realloc` may return a new address
- you do not terminate the string.

The following fixes these errors and includes some suggestions:

```
char *input(void)
{
    size_t i=0;
    int c;
    char *str = malloc(1);
    if (!str) return 0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n')
    {
        str[i]= c;
        if ((newstr = realloc(str,i+1))==0)
            break;          // out of memory: return what we have
        str= newstr;
        i++;
    }
    str[i]= '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest two changes: (1) Skip `sizeof(char)`, which is always 1, and at least to me it is a code smell. (2) Use an integer as index into the allocated string instead of an extra pointer, to avoid the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: The code shown will fail miserably if `EOF` is detected before a new-line had been read.

Comment: This `if (newstr != str) ` might invoke undefined behaviour, as`str` might point to invalid memory after `realloc()`.

Comment: @alk, fixed `EOF`. I am not sure about the undefined behavior comment. The `str` pointer (a variable) is compared with another pointer (variable), no matter if the memory pointed to is still valid. If it is undefined behavior, then it is not possible to check if the new pointer is different from the old pointer and the assignment must always be made.

Comment: "*it is not possible to check if the new pointer is different from the old pointer*" that's true. But one never needs to do this.

Comment: C 11 Annex J.2/1: "*The behaviour is undefined in the following circumstances: [...] - The value of a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended is used. - The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
indeterminate.*"

Comment: C 11 6.2.4/2: "*[...] The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.*"

Comment: @chux: fixed (removed flawed version from answer).

Comment: `input()` does not distinguish between reading `'\n'` and a lone end-of-file.  Code could use before `return str;` --> `if (ch == EOF && i == 0) { free(str); str = 0; }` to distinguish.  Other minor issues too, but still a good `input()` for OP.

Comment: @chux...hmmm... Returning empty string could mean "nothing read" and returning null means out-of-memory?

Comment: Yes but I'd expect the calling code would want to discern reading `"\n"`, and end-of-file.  Both are common.  Out-of-memory and the rare EOF due to input error are of lesser concern.

Answer (score 2):

After doing `str++`, the pointer no longer points to the start of the allocated string. `realloc` needs the original pointer, not one that points to somewhere inside the allocated data.

Answer (score 0):

An approach with no redundant calls and complete error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *input(void)
{
  size_t n = 0;
  char * str = NULL;

  do
  {
    ++n;

    {
      void * pv = realloc(str, (n + 1) * sizeof *str);
      if (NULL == pv)
      {
        perror("realloc() failed");

        break;
      }

      str = pv;
    }

    {
      int result = getchar();

      if (EOF == result)
      {
        if (ferror(stdin))
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "getchar() failed\n");
        }

        --n;

        break;
      }

      str[n - 1] = result;
    }
  } while ('\n' != str[n - 1]);

  if (NULL != str)
  {
    str[n] = '\0';
  }

  return str;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* Be optimistic. */

  char * str = input();
  if (NULL == str)
  {
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;

    fprintf(stderr, "input() failed\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("input is: '%s'\n", str);
  }

  free(str);

  return result;
}
```